# jQuery method to get one node - rather than find();

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I've been Googling this for an hour and can't seem to find the answer.

I'm using `$(xml).find('title')` -- but it seems to be returning all the "titles" in all nodes.  How do I just grab the title within the root node?

```
<response stat="OK">
    <title>Some Document</title>
    <menu>
        <item>
            <title>Some Title</title>
            <url>/</url>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Some Title 1</title>
            <url>/asdfasdf/</url>
        </item>
    </menu>
</response>
```

returns "Some DocumentSome TitleSome Title 1"

```
// Loads the page content and inserts it into the content area
$.ajax({
    dataType:   'xml',
    url:        'someurl',
    success:    function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

        // returns 
        console.log($(data).find('title').text());


    }
```

I just want the first title!  I would rather not use xpath, i'd rather use the cheapest  solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead, like this:

```
console.log($(data).children('title').text());
```

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only looks at the *first* level down.